# Get signed image url from S3 in Ionic page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, amazon-s3

In ionic, I have an array of image keys. Using these keys we want to get an Amazon S3 signed URL.

I have :

```
 <div *ngFor="let image of item.images">
    <div>Key: {{image}} -- Url: {{getImageUrl(image) }}</div>
 </div>
```

In the Javascript part I have following:

```
 getImageUrl(imageKey) {
    this.s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {'Key': imageKey}, (err, url) => {
      console.log(url);
      return url;
    });
  }
```

In the logs I do see the URLs are correctly. However in the html page; there is nothing. I have tried many things; e.g. by having the method getImageUrl create a new variable; this remained undefined.

How should I modify my code to get this working?

I strongly have the impression that this is caused by the asynch nature of angularJS/Ionic/... and that probably I need to work with callbacks. However; I can't get my head around how you would get that callback into the HTML...
I hope this is a beginner's question!

thanks!

Comment: where are you calling getImageUrl

Comment: Sorry, wrong copy paste. I call it in the html. I adjusted the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you want to display an image, you should use the  tag, empty div wont show anything, try this

```
<div *ngFor="let image of item.images">
    <div>
    <h1> Key: {{image}} -- Url: {{getImageUrl(image) }}
     </h1>
      <img *ngIf="image" [src]= {{getImageUrl(image) }}>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Small item on the notation: it seems to be:         
<img *ngIf="image" [src]="getImageUrl(image)">

The function now seems to be called many times (why not one time?); but the result is <img src="null"> in my browser...

Comment: because you are calling inside ngFor. you need to use |async pipe since the result is asynchronous